# I am not able to setState in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, setstate

In this project I want to set the state of the `userType` using the data that I retrieved from the `firebase` db. fetching from the `firebase` is working correctly but I cant set the state of `userType` from there

I already tried
`this.setState=({userType:snapshot.val()})`
                `this.state=({userType:snapshot.val()})`

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase';


    export default class Home extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state=({
          userId:firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
          userType:'f'
        })
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.readUserData();
      };
      readUserData=()=> {
        userstype= 'users/'+ this.state.userId + '/userType'

        firebase.database().ref(userstype).on('value', function (snapshot) {
          this.setState=({userType:snapshot.val()})
        });

          alert(this.state.userType)
        }


      render() {
        return (

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Taams</Text>
            <Text style={styles.edition}>Developer's Edition</Text>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Home</Text>
            <Text>Alpha 0.0.0.1</Text>
          </View>
          )}}
```

Comment: you are mutating setState instead of invoking it. just do `this.setState({ userType: snapshot.val() })`

Comment: @AsafDavid still showing error

Comment: i fixed it. now it working fine readUserData=()=> { userstype= 'users/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/userType' firebase.database().ref(userstype).once('value').then(snapshot => { this.state=({ uType: snapshot.val() }) })

Comment: You shouldn't reassign `this.state`. read this https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Answer (score 0):

I've update your setState method

Try below code

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';
 import * as firebase from 'firebase';


    export default class Home extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state=({
          userId:firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
          userType:'f'
        })
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.readUserData();
      };
      readUserData=()=> {
        userstype= 'users/'+ this.state.userId + '/userType'

        firebase.database().ref(userstype).on('value', function (snapshot) {
          this.setState({userType:snapshot.val}, () => {
            alert(this.state.userType)
          })
        });


        }


      render() {
        return (

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Taams</Text>
            <Text style={styles.edition}>Developer's Edition</Text>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Home</Text>
            <Text>Alpha 0.0.0.1</Text>
          </View>
          )}}
```

Hope this will work for you!
Thanks

Comment: It produced and error undefined is not a function firebase.database().ref(userstype).on('value', function (snapshot) {
          this.setState({userType:snapshot.val}, () => {
            alert(this2.state.userType)
          })

Comment: this error from firebase not from our side

try to solve this one@

Comment: i fixed it. now it working fine readUserData=()=> { userstype= 'users/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/userType' firebase.database().ref(userstype).once('value').then(snapshot => { this.state=({ uType: snapshot.val() }) })

Comment: great @SvdKs :)
is my answer helpful to you ?

Comment: Good Glad to hear :)